# What is the equivalent of Pattern.quote() for MessageFormat?

Tags: java, messageformat

I ran into an issue today with the following code using Spring:

```
String tabTitle = messageSource.getMessage(tabName, new Object[] {}, tabName, locale)
```

This is used to get the displayed titles of a series of tabs at the top of our site (an instance of [uPortal](https://github.com/Jasig/uPortal)). The problem is that if `tabName` contains a single quote, it gets automatically removed from the result. For example `What's For Lunch` becomes `Whats For Lunch`.

I've tracked down why and it is because the 3rd parameter in that method is supposed to be of the format specified in [java.text.MessageFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html). 2 single quotes are needed.

Because we're not passing any parameters with the format, I can safely escape any special characters in the `tabName` before passing it in as the 3rd parameter. I could manually replace the single quotes here with 2 single quotes, but what I'd really like is something like `Pattern.quote()`, only for the `MessageFormat` language, that would be guaranteed to handle all escaping. Does anything like this exist?

Comment: There isn’t, but you can safely do the `'` → `''` substitution, then enclose the entire thing in single quotes.  Doubled single-quotes are interpreted properly even inside single-quoted text.

Comment: Thanks, if you add this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn’t any method for it, but enclosing the entire text in ASCII single-quote characters will accomplish the same thing.  You can do `'` → `''` substitution as you’ve described, then surround the text with `'`.  From the [MessageFormat documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html):

> For example, pattern string `"'{''}'"` is interpreted as a sequence of `'{` (start of quoting and a left curly brace), `''` (a single quote), and `}'` (a right curly brace and end of quoting), *not* `'{'` and `'}'` (quoted left and right curly braces): representing string `"{'}"`, not `"{}"`.